# How to install minikube in CentOS which is deployed using virtual box

Tags: docker, kubernetes, centos, virtualbox, minikube

I have created a CentOS vm using virtual box and installed docker, now after installing minikube when i start minikube using driver as none it is giving me error regarding a dependency i.e conntrack, so i install it but even after installing it I am getting a same error when i start the minikube with driver as none. Can anyone please help me here

Tried on both CentOS7 and CentOS 8 but getting same error.

Comment: Attaching [installation guide](https://faun.pub/installing-minikube-on-virtual-machine-centos-using-container-getting-started-with-kubernetes-fea63893263) by adil, try those steps mentioned in it and let me know if you face any error.